# Vast memory required with UICollectionView images set from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uiimage

I'm making an app which has lots of entries from a database displayed in a `UICollectionView`, and each item in the collectionview displays an image. However, there are lots of duplicate images (ie, my `UICollectionView` has 200 items but there's only about 30 possible images).

Initially I assigned these images by calling `cell.imageview.image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile]` in my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, but that caused a bit of scrolling lag, presumably due to having to read the image from the internal memory each time.

Now I want to do all the I/O in `viewDidLoad` by creating an array/dictionary and just referencing that each time `cellForItem` is called. When I do this and create a dictionary of `UIImages` in viewDidLoad and have `cell.imageview.image = [imageDictionary objectForKey:]` it displays images correctly and scrolls really smoothly but the memory used is huge (it just increases till it's scrolled all the way to the bottom so I presume it has all 200 image instances in the RAM).

However, if alternatively I fill the dictionary in `viewDidLoad` with `NSData` of the image and set the image using `cell.imageView = [UIImage imageWithData:[dataDictionary objectForKey:]]`, the memory used is far more efficient and reflects only what is currently displayed on the screen. However, the scrolling becomes slightly laggy again.

My question is: why does the memory leak only occur when I fill the dictionary with UIImages rather than NSData? Does iOS automatically cache images unexpectedly or something?

Hope that made sense - it's hard to be clear without going too much into the detail of my code.

Comment: So if you only have 30 possible images, why are you loading all the duplicates? Are the duplicates easily identifiable (by file name or something like that)?

Comment: Yeah the datasource specifies the necessary image file name for each item. I'm not sure I understand your question - the only time I load duplicate images is inside `cellForItem` and I have to do it there right? Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, sorry!

Comment: When you create the dictionary of images in viewDidLoad, do you have 200 images in that dictionary or 30, and how are you creating those images?

Comment: Ah I see - it has the 30 images - the objects are UIImages and the keys are the file path of each UIImage. I create each image in the dictionary by calling `imageWithContentsOfFile`.

Comment: So the dictionary has only 30 keys, or do you mean it only has 30 different images, but 200 keys?

Comment: No - 30 images, 30 keys.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure how you could get 200 instances of the images in RAM then, if that's your problem. How are you populating 200 items using objectForKey: when you only have 30 keys?

Comment: Because not every item needs a unique image - lots of items will have the same image.Like how a list of all 200 mp3s on my phone might only need 30 images to display album artwork for every song as many songs will be from the same album and so will have the same image.

Answer (score 0):

Use your first approach to set the image as you scroll.  However, load the images in a background thread and then set the image on the main thread so you don't inhibit scrolling.  Also, make sure your images are the same size as the image view (ie. not huge) so they don't take up a ton of memory.

Example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile... // do stuff

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

        [[cell imageView] setImage:image];

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I'd actually already done this and found it worked very well, but still not quite as well as the method I describe that caused the memory problems, so I'm wondering if there's a way to make that one work :)

Comment: Preloading the images are always going to be great for performance but not memory.  Maybe cache the next and previous 2 rows in memory and load the rest accordingly as the table scrolls?